# JQuery works on Firefox not on Chrome

Tags: jquery

I have a two functions like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div').hover(
            function() { $('> span', this).show(); }, 
            function() { $('> span', this).hide(); }
        );
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    !function(d,s,id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=?&count=5", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
            $('.tweets').append('<div id='+data[index].id+'>'+data[index].text+'&nbsp<span style="display:none"class="hideTweeterIcons"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='+data[index].id+'"><img src="//si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/reply.png"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='+data[index].id+'"><img src="//si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/retweet.png"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='+data[index].id+'"><img src="https://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/favorite.png"></a></span></div><hr>');
        });     
    });
</script>
```

However, the hover part of function does not work in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox. What's wrong? I know that Chrome has better webkit. What's wrong ?

Comment: First, FF has no Webkit, it uses the Gecko Engine. I'm not sure, but it could be, that the selector does not work in Webkit.

Comment: I can't comment since I don't have enough street cred, so I'm commenting here. Have you tried debugging in Chrome using the ctrl+shift J and reloading page to see if any script errors show up?

Answer (score 1):

Write them this way and they gonna work fine:

```
$('div').hover(function()
    {
        $(this).find('span').show();
    }, function()
    {
        $(this).find('span').hide();
    });
```

let me know if this has worked, and if you need another scenario, let me know so I may modify my answer, thanks.

Comment: ok, describe to me what exactly is the wrong behavior, and what do you expect it to do.
Consider my live example as your project.

Comment: hm sorry it works but problem is that it affects other spans and also it visibles all spans. Is there a way to visible the effective one ? I tried this.show(); but does not work